# asp tags don't get rendered in a form

Tags: html, master-pages, umbraco

I have a masterpage that contains an application form, it has a set of questions on it and then right at the end it's supposed to have between 0 and 5 additional questions depending on the position applied for. Here's the code snippet from the Apply.Masterpage file:

```
<div class="row">
      <label>Please specify the main 3 software languages / technologies you have worked with in the last 5 years, and at what level you would rate yourself (between 1 and 5 where 1 is poor and 5 is excellent) * 
              <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionC" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10"></asp:TextBox>

              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="QuestionCRequired" ControlToValidate="QuestionC"
              ErrorMessage="Please provide a mobile phone number." runat="server" />
      </label>
</div>
```

and this is fine, prints the text box with working validator and a label, however the problems starts with the code that 's placed right below it:

```
<% 
  string[] questions = new string[] { "question1", "question2", "question3", "question4", "question5" };
      foreach (var question in questions)
      {
          if(!(umbraco.library.GetItem(question).Equals("", StringComparison.Ordinal)))
          {
             var questionRequired = (question + "Required"); 
             %>
             <div class="row">
                <label><%:question%>+<%:umbraco.library.GetItem(question)%>
                      <asp:TextBox ID=<%:question%> runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10"></asp:TextBox>
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID=<%:questionRequired%> ControlToValidate=<%:question%>
                      ErrorMessage="Please anwer the question" runat="server" />
                 </label>
             </div>
         <%}
      }%>
```

which is supposed to print two additional textboxes, but it prints:

```
question1+ksdgfjsdgfjsdg
question2+jugkjfkhfkhg
```

Where question1 is a name of field in Umbraco and "ksdgfjsdgfjsdg" is the actual question, so it picks the right data from Umbraco, but it seems like it skips the asp tags which is strange because the work fine a couple of lines above. The only difference is the use of <% %> tags in the additional question. How do I make the text box appear? I was trying to put the code responsible for printing additional questions in the macroScript but I only got as far as I am now.

Answer (score 0):

I could be totally wrong here, but I'm not sure you can dynamically create asp.net textboxes in this way. That's why it's only giving you the items immediately after the label tag.

I think if you want to dynamically create them you have to do something like

```
myTextBox = new TextBox();
myTextBox.ID = "txtIDGoesHere";
PanelForMyTextBox.Controls.Add(myTextBox);
```

But I may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: did not work with what I have implemented already, but thanks for trying :)